# how to send parameter from servlet to jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I want to pass parameter from servlet to jsp page . That is why , in servlet , I have written the following code :

```
request.setAttribute("errorMessage", dbMessage);
response.sendRedirect(redirectURL + "index.jsp");
```

In index.jsp I have written the following code :

```
<%
                        String error_msg = (String)request.getAttribute("errorMessage");
                        out.println(error_msg);
                        if (error_msg != null) {%>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <%=error_msg%> 
                        </div>
                    <%  }  %>
```

But I do not have the value of errorMessage in index.jsp page. What is the reason ? Please help me . Point to be noted : error Message is not null .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not pass hidden params while using request.sendRedirect. You have following options to pass parameters to the JSP from servlet.

1. Set request params in the url itself as

`response.sendRedirect(redirectURL + "index.jsp?errorMessage=", dbMessage);`

and then in JSP change code to

`String errorMsg = request.getParameter("errorMessage")`

**Error message will be visible in URL on the browser side.**

2. Use server-side forwarding as mentioned in the answer by Jaydip as shown below.

`request.setAttribute("errorMessage", dbMessage);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = serveltContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);`

3. Using session

   `request.getSession().setAttribute("errorMessage", dbMessage);`

   on the JSP, change code to

   `String error_msg=(String)request.getSession().getAttribute("errorMessage");`
4. Using cookie

   `Cookie errorCookie = new Cookie("errorMessage", dbMessage);
   errorCookie.setPath(request.getContextPath());
   response.addCookie(errorCookie);`

On browser side you can read cookie via js or from the request itself

```
String error_msg = null;
Cookie [] cookies = request.getCookies();
for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
    if ("errorMessage".equals(cookie.getName())) {
        error_msg =  cookie.getValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        **request.getSession().setAttribute("mango", "Mango is a sweet Fruit");**
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/index.jsp");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are using sendRedirect. Understand that sendRedirect will initiate new request to different url. Try to using forward or include to maintain the request parameter.

Comment: Can you give an example how to do this using forward or include ?

Comment: If I forward request from servlet to jsp page , then the url of serlet is shown but the content of jsp page is shown . why ?

Comment: Because forward works on server side and hence client doesn't know the request has been forwarded internally. Hence you are seeing original request url in browser.